# Kubectl get pod shows ErrImageNeverPull mysql

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubectl

According to this [docu](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/kubernetes-mysql), i try to lunch mysql with kubernetes:

deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kazi-db
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql:5.6
          name: mysql
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-secret
                  key: password
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

mysql-storage.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

service.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kazi-db
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
```

db-secret.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: kazi-db
type: kubernetes.io/basic-auth
stringData:
  password: xcvas
```

I have registered all with `kubectl apply -f ...`

The problem when i call `kubectl get pod`

```
kazi-db-758b978ccc-7m29n                                        0/1     ErrImageNeverPull   0          4m48s
```

I have a docker hub with integrated kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

- May be thats because of 1. imagePullPolicy is set to "Never" **and** 2. `image: mysql:5.6`  does not seem to be present on the worker node where this pod got scheduled.
- following are the two possible options:

  - Perform a manual pull of the `image: mysql:5.6` on all worker nodes using
    `docker pull mysql:5.6`
  - change `imagePullPolicy` to `IfNotPresent`.

Comment: sorry, but the two possible options didn't help me. I have now `ErrImagePull`

Comment: is ```docker pull mysql:5.6``` working on worker nodes ? what is the output of it ?

Comment: What is the k8 version? is this happening only for this image or for everything else?

Comment: k8 version `v1.22.4`.  `docker pull mysql:5.6                       
5.6: Pulling from library/mysql
no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries`

Comment: so that indicates that there is no image with the name ``` mysql``` on repo , Hence the error errimagepull .

Comment: @emoleumassi You need to use MySQL 8.0 or newer to run on docker ARM64 architecture.

Comment: @emoleumassi

MySQL Server 8.0, the latest GA, for both x86 and AArch64(ARM64) architectures (tag: 8.0, latest) (mysql-server/8.0/Dockerfile)

https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/

Comment: it works with version 8.0